# How to add numbers from a for loop in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I tried to make a loop that ranges from 1 to 101 and then I tried to add those numbers to a list, but when I run the code, it makes a new line from every number it added so it will look like a huge half pyramid. I want my code to make a single line that shows all numbers in that list.

Here's the code:

```
nr_random = []
x = 1
for x in range(1, 101):
    nr_random.append(x)
    print(nr_random)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just print the numbers in the list after the for loop executes:

```
x=1
for x in range(1,101):
    nr_random.append(x)
print(nr_random_greu)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just write print(nr_random_greu) outsite the loop

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable for the last added item:

```
x=1
nr_random = []    
for x in range(1,101):
    nr_random.append(x)
    last_element = nr_random[-1]
    print(last_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding numbers to the list (assumed to be `nr_random`) correctly. Just print the list outside the for loop. Everytime you print it inside it will print the list filled till the ith iteration of the loop on a new line.